# Select without ResultSetPrototype

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I have a class that inherits from TableGateway for selecting objects.
I have set the ResultSetPrototype of this TableGateway class to a HydratingResultSet in order to get entity objects rather than a normal result when selecting something.

But now I want to select something without the ResultSetPrototype being applied to the fetched values. It's an SQL statement that selects a maximum value of a column.
But since I have set the ResultSetPrototype, I get back an entity object with only null values.

Is this possible or do I have to save the adapter I inject in the constructor into a variable and use the adapter instead of the TableGateway?

Comment: Your Service-Class would simply overwrite the `ResultSetPrototype` of the `TableGateway` when doing `getSomeColumnCount()`.

Comment: How would I do that? Can you give an example?